# Get earliest date, vendor, qty for two joined tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query I use to bring data into a Crystal Report; it collapses data so that I get one record for each unique STOCK_ID, and logic and formatting in Crystal depends on that.

Now I need to add three more columns on the report.  Isolated, the query looks something like this:

```
*SELECT LINE.STOCK_ID ,LINE.QTY ,LINE.ORD_NUMB ,LINE.LINE_NUMB ,ORDER.DATE ,ORDER.VENDOR ,ORDER.STATUS ,PRODUCT.COUNT
FROM tbl_LINE LINE
JOIN tbl_ORDER ORDER ON LINE.ORD_NUMB = ORDER.ORD_NUMB
JOIN tbl_PRODUCT PRODUCT ON LINE.STOCK_ID = PRODUCT.STOCK_ID
WHERE ORDER.STATUS < 600 AND PRODUCT.COUNT > 1
ORDER BY LINE.STOCK_ID ,ORDER.DATE*
```

This pulls in multiple LINE.QTY, ORDER.DATE, ORDER.VENDOR, and for a STOCK_ID, but I need to collapse to get only the most recent ORDER.DATE, along with the other two associated columns.

I have no solution for doing this with joined tables.

Any insights.

Comment: search for `top-n-per-group` or `greatest-n-per-group`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT LINE.STOCK_ID ,LINE.QTY ,LINE.ORD_NUMB ,LINE.LINE_NUMB ,ORDER.DATE ,ORDER.VENDOR ,ORDER.STATUS ,PRODUCT.COUNT
FROM tbl_LINE LINE
JOIN tbl_ORDER ORDER ON LINE.ORD_NUMB = ORDER.ORD_NUMB
JOIN tbl_PRODUCT PRODUCT ON LINE.STOCK_ID = PRODUCT.STOCK_ID
JOIN 
(
    SELECT PRODUCT.STOCK_ID, max(ORDER.DATE) as MaxOrderDate
    FROM tbl_LINE LINE
    JOIN tbl_ORDER ORDER ON LINE.ORD_NUMB = ORDER.ORD_NUMB
    JOIN tbl_PRODUCT PRODUCT ON LINE.STOCK_ID = PRODUCT.STOCK_ID
    WHERE ORDER.STATUS < 600 AND PRODUCT.COUNT > 1
    GROUP BY PRODUCT.STOCK_ID
) x on LINE.STOCK_ID = x.STOCK_ID and ORDER.DATE = x.MaxOrderDate
WHERE ORDER.STATUS < 600 AND PRODUCT.COUNT > 1
ORDER BY LINE.STOCK_ID ,ORDER.DATE
```

Comment: Thank you.
This returns an error that PRODUCT.STOCK.ID in line 7 need to be part of an aggregate function or grouping.

Comment: I added a GROUP BY in the sub-query. Try that.

Comment: On the path, but there's still a glitch.  An ORDER has multiple LINES, but one DATE.  If the ORDER has multiple LINES for the same STOCK_ID, it pull it for each instance.

Comment: In the final splice into my existing query, I won't need the actual ORDER or LINE, just DATE, VENDOR, and QTY, so maybe SELECT DISTINCT will be able to get me there...

Comment: In the end, I needed to Sum Product.Count, drop a few Columns from the Select, only to find out the data needs serious cleanup.

But we do have proof-of-concept.  Thank you